# Xpath with two equals brother nodes with different values in a conditional

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following snippet of a xml document:

```
 <masternode>
     <node1>
            <node2>value_node2_1</node2>
            <node2>value_node2_2</node2>
            <node3>value_node3</node3>
     </node1>
     <node1>
            <node2>value_node2_3</node2>
            <node2>value_node2_4</node2>
            <node3>value_node3</node3>
     </node1>
 </masternode>
```

I'm trying get the value of node3 with the following xpath:

/masternode/node1[node2="value_node2_1"][node2="value_node2_2"]/node3

but it's not working because I have node2 twice like a condition. Is there another way to write the xpath?

Comment: Your XPath expression works for me with `lxml` in Python. What package/framework/language are you using?

Comment: I'm using VBA in a Excel customization

Comment: `/masternode/node1[node2="value_node2_1"][node2="value_node2_2"]/node3` can be written as `/masternode/node1[node2="value_node2_1" and node2="value_node2_2"]/node3` and as `/masternode/node1[node2= ("value_node2_1", "value_node2_2")]/node3` (in XPath 2.0 only) but I agree with the comment by Paul that your path should select a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention VBA I assume you use something like `New MSXML2.DOMDocument` or `CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")` or `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")`. These by default do not use the W3C standard XPath 1.0 as the query language but a nowadays undocumented proprietary selection language. Either use MSXML 6 with code like `New MSXML2.DOMDocument60` or `CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")` as that way you get XPath 1.0 support out of the box or set

```
doc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

on your document object before doing any `doc.selectNodes` respective `doc.selectSingleNode` calls. That way your posted XPath 1.0 sample should then work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll give you a feedback soon I try this way.

Comment: Martin, the query works now! I used MSXML 6 like you sugested, but now I'm having problems with the namespaces. When I don't specify the version of DomDocument i.e. , just DomDocument, the namespaces were being recognized but using DomDocument6.0 I have to declare one by one.

Comment: With the MSXML XPath API it is true, you have to use e.g. `doc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmls:foo='http://example.com/' xmlns:bar="http://example.org/'"`. As far as I know, that does not depend on the version of MSXML, if you use DOMDocument you implicitly use MSXML 3.0 and if you there want to use XPath and therefore set `doc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"` you have to set the namespaces the same as with MSXML 6.